# Express Validator, one function that will check multiple forms

Tags: node.js, express, validation, express-validator

I have been attempting to use Express Validator, however I have come across a problem.

Currently, I am using one route with a variable (which is the action, e.g update name, email, password etc.) to send the updated user data to the server.

I am using a switch statement that looks at the action, and does the relevant update to the user data.

I'd like one validation function that also has a switch statement, which will determine what it needs to validate.

Currently I have this so far...

this validation rules:

```
const validationRules = () => {
  console.log("validating...");

  return [
    // names must be 1 or more
    body("firstName").isLength({ min: 1 }),
    body("lastName").isLength({ min: 1 }),
  ];
};
```

the post request:

```
app.post(
  "/api/user/update/:action",
  validationRules(),
  validate,
  (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.body;
    const { action } = req.params;

    const updateDatabase = (id, updateObject) => {
      UserModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: id },
        { $set: updateObject },
        {
          useFindAndModify: false,
        }
      )
        .then((user) => {
          console.log(user);
          res.sendStatus(200);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(403).send({ error: err });
        });
    };

    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    } else {
      let update = {};

      switch (action) {
        case "name":
          const { firstName, lastName } = req.body;
          update = {
            "userInfo.firstName": firstName,
            "userInfo.lastName": lastName,
          };
          break;

        case "email":
          const { email } = req.body;
          console.log(email);
          update = {
            "userInfo.email": email,
          };
          break;

        case "mobile":
          const { mobile } = req.body;
          update = {
            "userInfo.mobile": mobile,
          };
          break;
        default:
          console.log("nothing matched so nothing updated");
          break;
      }
      updateDatabase(id, update);
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple middlware and the switch case there:

Here is an example:

```
const app = require('express')();

const validatorMiddleware = (req, res, next)=>{
  switch(req.params.action){
    case 'foo':
      //here you will `return` the rules
      console.log('foo');
      break;
    case 'bar':
      //here you will `return` the rules
      console.log('bar');
      break;
    default: console.log("default");
  }
  next();
}
app.get('/:action', validatorMiddleware, (req, res)=>{
  res.send(req.params);
})

app.listen(8080, ()=>{
  console.log('started');
})
```

For your case it will be something like this:

```
const validationRules = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("validating...");
  switch (req.params.action) {
    case "name":
      return [
        // names must be 1 or more
        body("firstName").isLength({ min: 1 }),
        body("lastName").isLength({ min: 1 }),
      ];
  }
  next();
};
```